# Widget onUpdate calls once

Tags: android, widget

I try create android widget:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onEnabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onUpdate " + Arrays.toString(appWidgetIds));
    }
}
```

When I start app first time I see log output: `D/myLogs: onUpdate [8]`

But if I press to this widget after that not happends. I expect that `D/myLogs: onUpdate [8]` prints again but it not true.

Answer (score 0):

> But if I press to this widget after that not happends

Correct. Your app widget has no UI, and in that UI you have not set a `PendingIntent` that would trigger `onUpdate()` (or anything else) to be called.

For example, here is an `AppWidgetProvider` that creates a UI and uses a `PendingIntent` to get control on clicks:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  Covered in detail in the book _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.appwidget.dice;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
  private static final int[] IMAGES={R.drawable.die_1,R.drawable.die_2,
                                      R.drawable.die_3,R.drawable.die_4,
                                      R.drawable.die_5,R.drawable.die_6};

  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context ctxt, AppWidgetManager mgr,
                        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    ComponentName me=new ComponentName(ctxt, AppWidget.class);

    mgr.updateAppWidget(me, buildUpdate(ctxt, appWidgetIds));
  }

  private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context ctxt, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews updateViews=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),
                                            R.layout.widget);

    Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, AppWidget.class);

    i.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0 , i,
                                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.left_die,
                                     IMAGES[(int)(Math.random()*6)]); 
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.left_die, pi);
    updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.right_die,
                                     IMAGES[(int)(Math.random()*6)]); 
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.right_die, pi);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.background, pi);

    return updateViews;
  }
}
```

(from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/AppWidget/PairOfDice) profiled in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android))

My `onUpdate()` method calls out to a `buildUpdate()` method. `buildUpdate()`:

- Creates a `RemoteViews` based on a layout, to define the basic UI of the app widget
- Identifies what images to show in two `ImageView` widgets in that layout (in this case, random images of six-sixed die faces)
- Creates an `Intent` that will invoke the same broadcast that was used to trigger my `onUpdate()` call
- Wraps that `Intent` in a broadcast `PendingIntent`
- Attaches the `PendingIntent` to the UI to respond to click events
- Uses that configured `RemoteViews` as the UI of the app widget

The result: when the user clicks on the images or background, the `AppWidgetProvider` is called again with `onUpdate()`, and the user sees an updated roll of the dice.

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to do it. but I can not understand how it works. I thought  that I should send an intent. But something must work to send it. I thought the  onUpdate method should  triger after press widget and in this mrthod create Intent and sent to service or activity. I just wand print to log - hello world.

Comment: @ip696: "I thought the onUpdate method should triger after press widget and in this mrthod create Intent and sent to service or activity" -- no, sorry.